# Проблема с использованием cx_Freeze

Tags: python

Вообщем нужно было скомпилировать питон программку в исполняемый файл, но у меня почему-то не получается! И я заметил, что не запускается программка, только если я импортирую какой-либо модуль! В чем может быть проблема? 
P.S. я уже даже понавтыкал через каждую строчку input() и заметил что прога падает при первом же импортировании модуля- это факт
UPD: оказывается что программа не запускается только в тот момент када импортирует модуль random !!! и я опять не знаю чего делать(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте больше подробностей, что не получается.

Дело в том, что эта библиотека компилирует все в *.pyc и засовывает в два архива (один с именем `library`, второй с именем вашего exe"шника), который по какой-то причине (может я не досмотрел) всегда должен быть в той же директории, что и ваш *.exe

Собственно этот архив и содержит все ваши исходники, которые вы явно указываете в проекте + которые вы явно укажете в setup.py

Кроме всего этого в кучу файлов вместе с *.exe еще добавится библиотека python32.dll и пара других файлов.

С помощью кое-каких настроек `Executable`, а именно:

```
include = ["blabla.mypackage"]
my_demo = Executable(script = "myDemo.py",
                     initScript = None,
                     path = "C:\\Python32-32",
                     targetName = "myDemo.exe",
                     includes = include,
                     copyDependentFiles = True, #эта и следующие две строки
                     appendScriptToExe = True,
                     appendScriptToLibrary = True,
                     icon = icon_file,
                     compress = True)
```

мне удалось добиться того, чтобы в итоге получалось на один архив меньше. Пытался использовать параметр `targetDir`, но получалось примерно то, что получается сейчас у вас, а именно почти ничего не получалось, он в нее не копирует необходимые файлы.

Как все это скомпилировать в один конкретный, на большинстве машин запускающийся exe"шник, я так и не разобрался.

Comment: да мне покачто впринципе не важно чтоб все это лежало в одном ехе прога тупо не запускается

Comment: и еще куда писать вот это все?)

Comment: в файл setup.py